# Method/Property Error on New SQL Server Connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string, sqlconnection

I'm running VB .Net in VS2013, on a Windows 8 over SQL Server 2008 R2, and my creation of an SQL Connection is failing with the error:

> *Property access must assign to the property or use its value.*

Here's my code:

Dim oCnn As SqlConnection
    Dim sCnn As String
    Dim bSunCnnOK as Boolean

```
Try
    If vsSunServer <> "" Then
        sCnn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
               "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
               "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
               "Initial Catalog=SunSystemsData;" & _
               "Data Source=" & vsSunServer
        oCnn = New SqlConnection(sCnn)
        oCnn.Open()
        bSunCnnOK = True
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    bSunCnnOK = False
End Try
```

`_vsSunserver_` is a string being passed in to the sub, and has a run-time value of `"SVRSUN07"`.

The error is being raised on the line:

```
oCnn = New SqlConnection(sCnn)
```

So at run-time, sCnn holds:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SunSystemsData;Data Source=SVRSUN07"
```

I've lifted this connection string from a .udl file, which returns successful when I Test Connection.

I can run SQLSMS over this database OK.

Comment: Couple of things.. If vsSunServer  is string then in If compare it against *String.empty* instead *<>*. Second try adding *''* *single quote* to vsSunServer like "Data Source='" & vsSunServer &"'"

Comment: I can't match that error message (its a compiler error, right, rather than a runtime one, despite you talking about runtime values) with the line you've identified as causing it. Have you tried re-starting (Visual Studio, and if that fails, your machine) and re-loading the code?

Comment: It IS actually a runtime error NOT a compile error...

Comment: Amnest - I've tried both those suggestions, but get the same error. (So connection string now reads _Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SunSystemsData;Data Source='svrsun07'_ .

Comment: That's a compiler error - you either get it when you compile the code, or you're getting it from the VS Debugger because you've got some expression in a debug window (such as immediate) that it can't compile. Either way, it's not coming, *specifically*, from that line of code you've identified.

Comment: Damien - quite correct, it *is* a compiler error... The actual error is _(...provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)_. When I compiled it and plugged in a MessageBox, this was the actual returned ex.Message value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. +1 for asking your first question well formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an ASCII art diagram that shows how the components related to each other. You are trying to use a SQL OLEDB connection string with SqlConnection. These things don't go together.

```
C#/VB.NET code -┬------------> SqlConnection -----------------┬-> SQL Server
                |                                             |
                ├--> OleDbConnection -┬-> SQL OLEDB provider -┤
                |                     |                       |
                |       Native code --┤                       |
                |                     |                       |
                └-> OdbcConnection ---┴-> SQL ODBC driver ----┘
```

If you really want to use the SQL OLEDB native provider then you can use [`OleDbConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This might be useful if you want your VB.NET code to be flexible and possible connect to other OLEDB providers such as Access, Postgres, Mysql, etc.

However if you know for sure that you will only be connecting to SQL Server then it will be easier to use `SqlConnection` instead with a connection string like `"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SunSystemsData;Data Source=SVRSUN07"`.